# Jenkins Grails plugin does not list lastest versions of Grails

Tags: grails, jenkins

When installing a new Grails from Jenkins web UI, a user is given the choice of some versions - up to 2.4.4 and 3.0, but 2.4.5 and 2.5 are missed.

How to add 2.4.5 to that list?

P.S. Jenkins 1.598, Grails plugin 1.7 (latest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an automated process within the Jenkins project infrastructure which updates the [list of available versions](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/updates/com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsInstaller.json) daily.
Your Jenkins installation periodically downloads this file and uses it to populate the version list in the web UI.

Unfortunately, at the time of asking this question, that automated process was [broken](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/INFRA-225?focusedCommentId=228764).

You can either wait for the bug to be fixed (it is now), or there should be the option to "Install from .zip/.tgz" instead of "Install from mirrors", where you can enter the URL to the Grails 2.4.5 zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to "Manage Jenkins"/"Configure System"/"Grails installations" and put there the path where your installation is.